# Showing Error while runing a file in QT

Tags: qt, x11

While building a project in QT 2.4.1
This error message shows:

```
error: cannot find -lX11

error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can any one please help?

Comment: set linked libraries properly. Also switch to Qt 5.x

Comment: Actually am new in this platform. I am using QT for the first time. So can anybody please elaborate the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Qt.  The problem is that your linker can't find `libX11.so`.

Answer (score 0):

`-lX11` is a compile/link flag related to the client libraries for xorg; at least install libx11-dev with `apt-get install libx11-dev` (you can have more dependencies to satisfy)